# Accessing Django app in Docker container from another Docker container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

### Objective

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that, among others, runs three Docker containers that are in the same network: a Django app, Nginx, and a Selenium image. My objective is to be able to test the Django app from the Selenium container.

### Problem

When trying to make get requests from the Selenium driver

```py
driver.get("http://nginx:80")
```

Django refuses the connection on the grounds that the host is disallowed. I get an:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'nginx'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
```

I tried adding the name of the container (Nginx) to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable in `settings.py` but it still somehow will not accept it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Simply put, RFC 1034/1035 doesn't allow underscores (_) in domain names, and it seems that Django checks for that. I simply changed them for hyphens (-) and the problem got fixed.